# Excel vba Method 'Sheets' fails if called from Thisworkbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to call a sub from Thisworkbook that resides in Module1 but end up with error message "Method 'Sheets' of object '_Global' failed". My sub in Module1 runs fine if run separatelly. My code in Thisworkbook is as simple as this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call gvGetDPMlist
End Sub
```

My code in Module1 is this:

```
Sub gvGetDPMlist()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("tDPM[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("filterSite_ID"), _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M1:O1"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's not the method call that is failing. Your `Sub gvGetDPMlist()` gets called from the `Sub Workbook_Open()` without any issues. Try replacing the code in `Sub gvGetDPMlist()` with just a message box. It gets called on the workbook open event without any errors.

Comment: Okay. But `Sub gvGetDPMlist()` works fine by itself?

Comment: Tried it putting Msgbox as you advise. The message appears just fine as you say. So where is the problem then?

Comment: Yes, it works fine if I run it separatelly both with Msgbox alone and with the AdvancedFilter action.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do here? It's not much clear from the single line of code written in `Sub vbGetDPMlist()`

Comment: I want to build a few lists for drop-down objects during file open. The lists are created from a "master" table by filtering it accordingly. So here gvGetDPMlist precedure is preparing one of the lists by using advanced filter to filter the necessary data into another location. I.e. if a sales manager in Chicago opens the file, he/she automatically gets the list of products in the drop-down list applicable to Chicago, but not New York.

Comment: The problem I have is that Workbook_Open event has to reside in Thisworkbook, as I understand. But filtering, if put into Thisworkbook, does not work. Therefore I am calling it from Workbook_Open.

Comment: The master table to be filtered is located in ThisWorkbook, or in the new workbook opened by the user?

Comment: The master table is this: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("tDPM[#All]") . It is in Sheet1 in the same workbook.

Comment: Can you post a link to your excel document? It's difficult to debug without test data. You can fill it with dummy data if you want.

Comment: Because the sheets may, or may not, have all been fully loaded when the Workbook_Open event is called, the usual fix for these situations is to process the code as you are saving the workbook instead - thus ensuring that it is already in the desired state when it is opened the next time.

Comment: @Nvj When I clean up all the code to post it here leaving only the simple part that I posted in the begining, I see that my code actualy works. Must be some other code in my Open event spoiling the things. At least I have something now to start with. I appreciate your help!

Comment: After some experiments I see that the problem is timing indeed. In fact in Workbook Open I have another substantial filtering and gvGetDPMlist relies on the result of that filter. How do I make first filter complete its task before invoking the second filter in Module1?

Comment: Try replacing `Sheets("Sheet1")` with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 0):

too long to be properly inserted in a comment, so I'm writing it as an answer

it may be a timing issue between the macro execution (which takes place immediately at workbook opening) and the worksheets actual availability

to test this you could refactor your code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub gvGetDPMlist()
    Dim IRng As Range, Crng As Range, oRng As Range

    Set IRng = Sheets("Sheet001").Range("tDPM[#All]")
    Set Crng = Sheets("Sheet003").Range("filterSite_ID")
    Set oRng = Sheets("Sheet001").Range("M1:O1")

    IRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Crng, CopyToRange:=oRng        
End Sub
```

so that you can see whether it's actually a timing issue (it should error out at the first `Set` statement) or an error taking place in `AdvancedFilter` execution (it should error out at `IRng.AdvancedFilter...` statement)

Comment: Tried that one in Module1. It does error out at the first Set statement.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation it looks like the problem lies in Excel Protected View Settings. I am opening my Excel file from local network share. If Protected View for files originating from Internet is enabled, Advanced Filter statement in vba fails even if I answer Enable when Excel starts. It works fine if this Excel option is disabled.